# Passing viewmodel to actionresult creates new viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am using a viewmodel, which i then when to send to an actionresult to use 
(the modified viewmodel)

But in the controller, i lose the list and objects in my viewmodel. This is my view:

```
@using PigeonFancier.Models
@model PigeonFancier.Models.InschrijvingModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateInschrijvingen","Melker",Model))
{
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <table>

            @foreach (var item in Model.inschrijvingLijst)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Duif.Naam)</td>                              
                    <td> @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.isGeselecteerd)</td>                              
                </tr>
            }
        </table>   
        <input type="submit" value="Wijzigen"/>
    </fieldset>
</div>
}
```

This is my controller, which does nothing at the moment until i can get the full viewmodel back from the view.

```
public ActionResult UpdateInschrijvingen(InschrijvingModel inschrijvingsModel)

    {
        // inschrijvingsModel is not null, but it creates a new model before 
            it comes here with 
        //Use the model for some updates

        return RedirectToAction("Inschrijven", new { vluchtId = 
                   inschrijvingsModel.vlucht.VluchtId });
    }
```

This is the model with the List and some other objects who become null because it creates a new model when it comes back from the view to the actionresult

```
public class InschrijvingModel
{
    public Vlucht vlucht;
    public Duivenmelker duivenmelker;
    public List<CheckBoxModel> inschrijvingLijst { get; set; }

    public InschrijvingModel()
    {
        // Without this i get, No parameterless constructor defined exception. 
        // So it uses this when it comes back from the view to make a new model
    }

    public InschrijvingModel(Duivenmelker m, Vlucht vl)
    {
        inschrijvingLijst = new List<CheckBoxModel>();
            vlucht = vl;
            duivenmelker = m;

        foreach (var i in m.Duiven)

        {
            inschrijvingLijst.Add(new CheckBoxModel(){Duif = i, 
            isGeselecteerd =  i.IsIngeschrevenOpVlucht(vl)});
        }

    }
```

What is going wrong and how should i fix this problem please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include all Lists and properties into your clearly defined Model.

Once you get your viewmodel in POST action, you perform your operation (create, edit, etc..) and if you want **to return to the same view**(that have post action) , you need to **re-populate all List values** (like drop-downs and check-box list) and set them on viewmodel that you return back.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a partial solution for the list by using

for and [i] instead of foreach

But the objects still are null, even when using int Id instead of the object

Also tried already with Html.hiddenfor for those objects doesn't work

Comment: Html.Hiddenfor Works for ints

But why doesn't it work for objects?

Comment: There is no way to represent an object like that in a Hidden field.  You need to represent each of the native typed fields that make up your object.

Comment: Ok if i do it for each native field it works to pass it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The approach used in this article may be a solution for you:

http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/09/preparing-list-of-objects-so-they-can.html